What are the differences and similarities between inflaton, dilaton, scaleron, and other similar hypothetical particles?
Lately I've been reading about modified gravity and I'm a bit lost on the names of hypothetical particles. Let me give an example. I was reading about Starobinsky inflation, which prescribes a gravitational action with a $R^2$ term. This can be recast in the form of a new scalar field. Since this field would be responsible for inflation, I naively guessed this would be what people call the "inflaton" (or an incarnation of it).
Trying to learn more about this, I came across the Living Review 1002.4928, about $f(R)$ theories. On sec. 2.2 the authors say

The $f(R)$ theory in the metric formalism can be cast in the form of Brans–Dicke (BD) theory with a potential for the effective scalar-field degree of freedom (scalaron).

The Scholarpedia article on $f(R)$ gravity also refers to the new scalar mode of $R^2$ gravity as a scaleron.
However, the parallel with Brans–Dicke theory confused me due to a second reason: I was previously under the impression that the name of the scalar field in Brans–Dicke theory was the dilaton (due to the Wikipedia page on the dilaton).
Given all of this, I'm now confused on what are the similarities and differences between inflatons, scalerons, dilatons, and whatever other similar particles there may be in modified gravity (maybe there is a name for the spin 2 massive ghost in quadratic gravity?). Hence, here is my question: how are these names used in the high-energy and modified gravity literature and what are the similarities and differences between them?
